# Talend/Nexus : is there a way to connect talend open studio with a nexus server

Tags: nexus, talend

I'm trying to connect my Talend Open Studio for ESB v7.3.1.20200219 with a nexus 3 server.
I tried to follow the tutorial on the help.talend.
I don't have the Artifact Repository menu to register the server.

[TOS for ESB menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgxsc.png)

So I assume that I don't have these because it's the open studio version, but is there a way to connect it anayway ?
I tried to look somewhere else but I didn't find anything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus Integration  is only available the Enterprise Edition. With the Community Edition, you are on your own to provide this kind of integration.

Or you can try the free `tNexusDeploy` Add-on available in the [Talend Exchange](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductoverview:marketplace=marketplace%252F1&p=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F1684&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F1684%252Fitems%252F2968).

- provides Nexus 2 and Nexus 3
- deploy DI jobs and OSGi bundles
- prevent errors in case the artifact exists already in a release repository
- delete the artifact file if successfully deployed optionally

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try your solution and give you a feed back :)

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, I finally had time to test your solution and it worked perfectly !!